# Kernel crash after simple input of variable defintion

Tags: bugs, kernel, crash, predictive-interface

**Fixed in 10.3.0**

---

I have encountered a very surprising and annoying kernel crash:

```
xxx = (-((I*b[-3] + (a[3] + I*d[-3])/Sqrt[2])*(c[5] + (I*(I*a[3] + d[-3]))/Sqrt[2]))/2 - ((I*b[-4] + (a[4] + I*d[-4])/Sqrt[2])*(c[4] + (I*(I*a[2] + d[-2]))/Sqrt[2]))/2 - ((I*b[-5] + (a[5] + I*d[-5])/Sqrt[2])*(c[3] + (I*(I*a[1] + d[-1]))/Sqrt[2]))/2 + ((b[2] + (I*(a[-2] + I*d[2]))/Sqrt[2])*(I*c[-1] + (I*a[-3] + d[3])/Sqrt[2]))/2 + ((b[1] + (I*(a[-1] + I*d[1]))/Sqrt[2])*(I*c[-2] + (I*a[-4] + d[4])/Sqrt[2]))/2 + ((b[0] + (I*(a[0] + I*d[0]))/Sqrt[2])*(I*c[-3] + (I*a[-5] + d[5])/Sqrt[2]))/2)^2
```

When I evaluate this expression, and the output is not supressed, my kernel repeatably crashes.

I have *Mathematica* 9.0.1.0 under Windows 8 (version 6.3). Can somebody confirm this? Is this behaviour known? Has it been fixed in newer versions?

Comment: no crash here Mma 10

Comment: Try restarting the kernel. There might be existing definitions of `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

Comment: Works fine on V10.4.1 running on OS X 10.10.2.

Comment: I can verify that it crashes the kernel in version 9.0 for Windows, but only when input comes from the Front End, not in the standalone kernel.

It seems to be fixed in later versions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug that has been fixed in Mathematica 10.3.0 and later.

The cause of the crash is one of the computations that the predictive interface tries in the background, so a workaround for earlier versions would be to [turn off the Suggestions Bar](http://support.wolfram.com/kb/12406) by unchecking the box in Preferences.